# Connect RFID readers with system/PC

Tags: smartcard, rfid, raspberry-pi

I have a **Raspberry Pi**, **HID smartcard** (HID iClass Px G8Y), **HID Card Reader** (RP40 multiClass).

What I am trying to do is to read the data from this smartcard via the Card Reader onto my system (Laptop/RasPi).

The Card reader has Ethernet as output which would connect to the system (I guess).

I am struggling to install the device drivers on the system and start developing. I have not worked on RFID sensors before.

Comment: if your question is how to install device drivers, you are not on the correct site

Comment: if your question is how to pair hardware to a RPi, you are also on the wrong site

Comment: My question is about connection. Please close if it's on wrong forum. Sincere apologies.